# Code works completely fine in Hackerrank but when printed out in my command prompt, it gives complete different outputs

Tags: c++, vim

I am new to C++ and I've been learning how to use Vim recently as my text editor. I was doing a really basic task on Hackerrank which inputted an int, long, char, float, and double separated by a space between them and the program had to output all of the values accordingly with the float value going up to 3 decimal places and the double to 9 decimal places. I completed the code on Hackerrank itself and it worked perfectly fine but when I tested the input in my own command prompt, it outputted different values that weren't the same as what it had outputted on Hackerrank. Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a;
    long b;
    char c;
    float d;
    double e;

    cin >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e;
    cout << a << '\n' << b << '\n' << c << '\n';
    cout << fixed << setprecision(3) << d << endl;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(9) << e << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My inputs were the following:
211916801 97592151379235457 p 19856.992 -5279235.721231465

The output in my command prompt was this instead: 
211916801 
2147483647 

0.000
0.000000000

while the output on Hackerrank was accepted as it came out like this: 
211916801 
97592151379235457 
p 
19856.992 
-5279235.721231465

The bind that I use to execute my program in my VIMRC is this: 
autocmd filetype cpp nnoremap  :w  !g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall % -o %:r && %:r.exe

Does anyone know why the code isn't executing properly on my Vim but works fine when it ran on Hackerrank? The first integer printed fine but then after b (long), it printed out random stuff instead. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code relies on `long` to occupy 64 bit. Which is often is not true. For example on 32 bit vc++ programs it occupies 32 bit. So you should use `long long` instead or (better) fixed size types from standard library, such as `::std::int64_t`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Just to clarify, is this int64_t library included under "using namespace std", meaning that I don't have to change anything in my code except "long" to "long long"?

Comment: @user11950757 `int64_t` is not a library, it is a type alias from standard library, included through `cstdint` header